# Is there a difference between the characteristic of $O_k/\mathfrak{p}$ and the ideal norm $||\mathfrak{p}||$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, normed-spaces, ideals

Let $L$ be number field and $K$ a finite field extension. Let $O_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$, and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal of $O_K$. I have the definition of the ideal norm:
$$
||\mathfrak{p}||=\# (O_K/\mathfrak{p})
$$
I'm now wondering if the field norm of $\mathfrak{p}$ is the same as the characteristic of $O_K/\mathfrak{p}$? I have defined the characteristic as:

"the smallest positive integer $n$ s.t. $1+...+1=0$ ($n$ times) in the ring; if no such integer exists the characteristic of the ring is said to be $0$".

I'm trying to connect the two definitions, but struggle a bit to do so. If the two things aren't equivalent, maybe one could give me a counterexample.

Comment: There is a link between the two quantities that you refer to, but they aren’t equal. For instance, the characteristic is always prime while the ideal norm isn’t. For instance, $(7)$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ with norm $49$.

Comment: How come we know the characteristic is always prime? This might be trivial, but please carry over with me

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ is a domain. Such rings always have prime or null characteristic (since if $c$ is the characteristic, then $\mathbb{Z}/(c)$ embeds into the ring hence is an integral domain too).

Comment: Thank you! @Mindlack